# Capitalizing the first letter of the first word in a sentence using StringBuilder

Tags: java

My assignment is to create twenty random sentences using the provided arrays. To get full credit, I need a period at the end of every sentence, and the first letter of each sentence needs to be capitalized.
I've figured out the period part, but I'm stuck on how to capitalize the first letter of the first word in every sentence. The assignment says I can use to.String to convert my StringBuilder back into as String where and when I need to, but I'm not sure where I would need to and if I would have to. I have attempted to use a capitalization method I've found online, but that just results in the error "command execution failed". Without the "capitalization attempt", the program functions as its supposed to, just with all lowercase letters. I am fairly new to Java and currently at a loss, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I HAVE to use StringBuilder to construct my sentences in order to get any credit

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomSentanceMaker {
  private static String [] Article = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
  private static String [] Noun = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"};
  private static String [] Verb = {"drove" , "jumped", "ran", "walked",   "skipped"};
private static String [] Preposition = {"to" , "from", "over" , "under" , "on"};

public static void main(String [] args){ 
   
   System.out.println("Below are 20 randomly created setences\n");
   
   for(int i = 0; i <=19; i++){
       System.out.println(RandomSentence());
   }
}

       public static StringBuilder RandomSentence(){
       Random rand = new Random();
       int[] index = new int[6];
       StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder Sentence = new StringBuilder();

       for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
           index[i] = rand.nextInt(5);
       }
                                //capitalization attempt 
       Sentence = buffer.append(Sentence.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + Sentence.substring(1)).append(Article[index[0]]).append(" ").append(Noun[index[1]]).append(" ").append(Verb[index[2]]).append(" ").append(Preposition[index[3]]).append("   ").append(Article[index[4]]).append(" ").append(Noun[index[5]]).append(".");
       return Sentence; 
      

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has occurred because you are trying to access the characters of `Sentence` StringBuilder which is empty as you haven't appended any string in the beginning. Hence we need to initialize the StringBuilder with a random Article first and then perform the capitalization as follows:

```java
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder Sentence = new StringBuilder(Article[index[0]]);
                                //capitalization attempt 
Sentence = buffer.append(Sentence.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + Sentence.substring(1)).append(" ").append(Noun[index[1]]).append(" ").append(Verb[index[2]]).append(" ").append(Preposition[index[3]]).append("   ").append(Article[index[4]]).append(" ").append(Noun[index[5]]).append(".");
```

Please note that I have removed the `.append(Article[index[0]])` part as we already have done that in the StringBuilder initialization.
Prints:

```
The dog walked under   one boy.
The girl drove over   some car.
A town jumped from   a town.
Some boy walked to   a dog.
A dog jumped to   some girl.
...and so on...
```

`RandomSentence` Method:

```java
    public static StringBuilder RandomSentence()
    {
       Random rand = new Random();
       int[] index = new int[6];
       

       for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
           index[i] = rand.nextInt(5);
       }
       StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
       StringBuilder Sentence = new StringBuilder(Article[index[0]]);
                                //capitalization attempt 
       Sentence = buffer.append(Sentence.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + Sentence.substring(1)).append(" ").append(Noun[index[1]]).append(" ").append(Verb[index[2]]).append(" ").append(Preposition[index[3]]).append("   ").append(Article[index[4]]).append(" ").append(Noun[index[5]]).append(".");
       return Sentence;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the very first word in your sentence in two using the String.substring method so that you have the first letter of that word alone in a string and the rest of the word in another one.
2. Uppercase the first string using the String.toUppercase method.
3. Concatenate both strings using your stringBuilder.